# Is it possible to paste PivotTable values without creating a PivotTable?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Currently I am creating a PivotTable, which I copy/paste the table **as values** to a separate sheet.

Instead of doing this, through VBA, is it possible to skip creating the actual PivotTable and just paste the values? Potentially using the PivotTable cache? My data will change everyday, but the PivotTable fields will be the same.

Thank you!

Comment: Not by using the `PivotCache`, no. You'd need to recreate the logic of the pivot table in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible with Power Pivot.

Select the Source data and Add it Data Model in Power Pivot

[image: Select data and add to model]

Then goto Data-> Existing Connections -> This Workbook Data Model -> Pivot Table Report

[image: Data Model]

Once the pivot table report is created , select the report

Goto PivotTable Analyze -> OLAP Tools -> Convert to Formulas

[image: OLAP Tools]

Your pivot report will be converted to formulas linked to Data Model using Cube Function.

You can now move individual data as you wish.

Just click Refresh All whenever the data is changed to refresh the data